# External USB HDD not being detected properly

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

My laptop (Arch Linux) refuses to recognize USB hard disk drives properly, while flash drives are working fine. The specific drive in question is a 500GB NTFS volume.

I’ve already encountered this problem on Linux some time ago, but now I forgot the solution and I fail to find any information on it. This should be caused by hard disk drive replying too slowly to computer’s requests, as a result of spin-up period, and Linux kernels are set to have an insufficient timeout period by default.

If anyone can suggest how to increase the timeout, please help.

`dmesg`:

```
[ 3029.227561] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 3032.176560] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 3037.043712] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3037.044732] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 3038.052900] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     StoreJet Transcend        01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[ 3038.053756] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[ 3038.053956] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3038.053960] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 3038.054153] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3038.054156] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3038.097712]  sdb:
[ 3038.099884] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

`fdisk /dev/sdb`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73696d20

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1       1919230059 6204919772 4285689714     2T  a OS/2 Boot Manager
/dev/sdb2        544829025 1089655755  544826731 259.8G 65 Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb3        168653938  168653938          0     0B 65 Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb4       2885681152 2885734080      52929  25.9M  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The drive does appear as `/dev/sdb`, but none of its partitions do. It works fine with Windows.

Comment: How did you try to mount it? Which command and options did you use?

Comment: @Hastur I did not try to mount it since there's nothing to mount. All the partitions listed in `fdisk` output do not really exist and none of them is what I expected to mount - a 500G NTFS filesystem.

Comment: If it is a spin problem I expect different output of fdisk if I plug the HDD more then one time. If it is always the same output it should be a sector of the MBR to be fixed, maybe only bad written. Check even SMART errors if it is possible. .

Comment: @Hastur Okay, if so, I'll attempt to search and apply an MBR fixing tool. Any advice on how to do that is much appreciated. But first of all I'll make sure that I did not harm it accidentally and it's still functional in Windows.

Comment: Do a Backup. After continue.  Some references to start to see: [gparted: FIX MS-DOS Partition](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php), [gparted FAQ](http://gparted.org/faq.php), [How to fix...](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/), [Arch-Linux ntfs3g](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G), [`ntfsresize`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsresize), some hints more [about fuse](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access)... read, feel, think, search more, but before Backup! :-)